# objection.js modifyEager .as('count') doesn't seem to do anything to .count()

Tags: node.js, mysql2, eager, objection.js

So I want to get the count of comments in a post rather than all the comments themselves
I've got it to work with modifyEager like so but the `as('count')` seems to be doing nothing in this case

```
.eager('comments').modifyEager("comments", builder => {
    builder.count().as('count')
})
```

It's really tedious because commentsCount for each post has these values:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[ Post { 'count(*)': 1 } ]
[]
```

So I have gotten the count doing this but I'm surely doing something wrong

```
if(commentCount.length > 0)
    return data[0]["count(*)"]
return 0
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: showing the working code for reference to help people

```
module.exports = async (organizationId, scope) => {
    return await Post.query()
    .where("organization_id", organizationId)
    .orderBy("post_id", "desc")
    .limit(scope.limit)
    .offset(scope.offset)
    .select(
        'posts.*',
        Post.relatedQuery('comments').count().as('commentsCount')
    )
    .eager('users')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldnt test it, but the example appears at docs this way:

```
const posts = await Post
  .query()
  .select(
    'Post.*',
    Post.relatedQuery('comments').count().as('numberOfComments')
  );

console.log(posts[4].numberOfComments);
```